# Send arbitrary FTP commands in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I've been doing plenty of stuff using PSFTP Module by Michal Gajda

Until I wanted to send arbitrary commands such as :

```
quote SITE LRECL=132 RECFM=FB
```

or

```
quote SYST
```

I have found that this can't be achieved using `FtpWebRequest`, but only a third-party FTP implementation.

I want to ask what is the best open source FTP implementation compatible with PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send an arbitrary FTP command with [WinSCP .NET assembly used from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) using the [`Session.ExecuteCommand` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand):

```powershell
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"
 
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = "example.com"
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
    $sessionOptions.Password = "password"
 
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
 
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Execute command
        $session.ExecuteCommand("SITE LRECL=132 RECFM=FB").Check() 
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }
 
    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

---

There's also the [PowerShell module](https://github.com/tomohulk/WinSCP) build on top of WinSCP .NET assembly that you can use like:

```powershell
$session = New-WinSCPSessionOptions -Protocol Ftp -Hostname example.com -Username user -Password mypassword | Open-WinSCPSession
Invoke-WinSCPCommand -WinSCPSession $session -Command "SITE LRECL=132 RECFM=FB"
```

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*